# No route to host using ssh

Tags: ssh

I have a issue with remote server connection using ssh. I have a serverA on xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 with default port 22. I have an another serverB on xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2 same default port22. Now I want to coonect serverB from serverA using ssh. I used the following command

```
[userA@localhost~] # ssh userB@serverB
```

When I run this command then I got the error as below

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 port 22: No route to host
```

One more this  when I login the serverA then I see the prompt like 
**[userA@Localhost~] #**

I did not understand that why it shows like above bold  text while it should be show as 
`[userA@serverA ~] #` 
Any one has any idea to resolve this issue.

updated

I already ping but got the below response

```
[userA@localhost ~]# /bin/ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
PING xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=5 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=6 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=8 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=11 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=17 Redirect Host(New nexthop: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1)
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=17 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.24.1 icmp_seq=18 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Updated-2

I run the netstat command and got the result as

```
[userA@localhost ~]# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.24.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.24.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: Look for any firewall on ServerB which might block the ssh connection. Use telnet as in `telnet xx.xx.xx.2 22` to test the connection. But first use `ping xx.xx.xx.2` and see if you get any response. Finally  `iptables -F; iptables -X` might also help.

Comment: @ val0x00ff : please see my updates. I already used ping command for both serverA and serverB and got the same result as shown in updates.

Comment: well, there's your answer. somethings redirecting you, probably some firewall.

Comment: @GhostAnswer Please show `route -n` or `netstat -rn` You've some routing issues.

Comment: @ val0x00ff : updates is available after run the command

Comment: @GhostAnswer delete the `192.168.24.0` and `169.254.0.0` network then add `192.168.24.0` and things will work just fine. BTW, don't put a space in `@ val0x00ff` otherwise I won't get notifications.

Comment: ok let me try and then I will tell you

Comment: It's ridiculous to hide IP addresses with start with 192.168 or 10. Those are not public IPs, so please put full IPs next time if they are not public. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network or https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918

Comment: +1 @JiriXichtkniha the masking of your IP addresses makes this question incredibly confusing, and your IP address range there is private, unaccessible and useless to anyone else. Literally millions of other people use those same addresses.  In the meanwhile you've obviously got a routing problem such as incorrectly specified default gateway, so it looks a lot like a basic "user misconfiguration" issue, so playing 'guess the numbers' when the numbers may well be wrong in the first place is ...

Comment: To remove the bold text, you will need to set/change the `PS1` variable. Look for `PS1=` in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I solved my issue before some days.